# diff and patch tool

Tags: diff, patch, meld

I'm trying to generate patches for a bunch of files I changed. I'm using [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) which does a great job of diff’ing the files in a nice visual manor, then it allows me to save and generate a patch file based on those changes.

The problem I have is that it's slow to do this one at a time. Is there a similar tool that I can use for batch work? I want it to recursively check all the files in two directories and generate all the patch files based on its findings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I've never used Meld, I have a feeling it's actually using 'diff' under the covers. The way I've always generated patch files is simple:

```
$ diff -ruN ${dir1} ${dir2} > ${patchfile}.patch
```

That generates a single large patch file, which you can then break up as apporpriate. To generate individual patch files for each change found, you would simply run that large file through a script that split when it saw a new changeset (a script I don't have handy or know of, since I've never used one like it).

Comment: I think you're right, I was not aware of the `-u` option for `diff`, that does make the formatting the same. How would I update that line to avoid certain files? For example any `*.o` files that are in the directories.

Comment: Use an --exclude={pattern} option. There are a number of options you may or may not want to use, I'd suggest reading through the man page to understand what's available. The diff program is actually quite powerful.

Answer (score 1):

That's what `diff` is for. `patch` takes `diff` output files as input. Just run `diff` in a BASH loop for each of your files. For example, if the original files are in dirA and the new ones in dirB (with the same filenames), do this (in ./dirA):

```
for n in $(ls * | grep -v ".o$"); do \
    diff -uN $n dirB/$n > $n.patch; patch $n < $n.patch; \
done
```

Comment: @Mike, see my updated answer for avoiding `.o` files.